# Pause and Resume ASINetworkQueue

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, nsoperationqueue

I'm using an ASINetworkQueue to download around 50 files in an iPad app. I'm looking for a way of allowing the user to pause and resume the queue.

The ASIHTTP docs refer to

```
[request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
```

but this operates at an individual request level, not at the queue level. As ASINetworkQueue is a subclass of NSOperationQueue I've also tried

```
[queue setSuspended:YES];
```

and while this will pause a queue, it does not affect the downloads in progress, it just waits until they've finished and then pauses the queue, which in my case means many seconds between the user pressing the button and the queue actually pausing, which is not the UI experience I want.

Can anyone suggest another way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

My solution..

```
- (void) pause
{
    if(self.queue && self.queue.requestsCount>0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", self.queue.operations);

        for (ASIHTTPRequest * req in self.queue.operations) {
            req.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1" forKey:@"ignore"];
        }

        [self.queue.operations makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(cancel)];

        [self.queue setSuspended:YES];

        for (ASIHTTPRequest * req in self.queue.operations) {
            ASIHTTPRequest * newReq = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:req.url];
            [newReq setDownloadDestinationPath:req.downloadDestinationPath];
            [newReq setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:req.temporaryFileDownloadPath];
//            [newReq setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
            [newReq setUserInfo:req.userInfo];
            [self.queue addOperation:newReq];

        }

    }
}

- (void) resume
{
    if(self.queue && self.queue.requestsCount>0)
    {
        [self _setupQueue];
        [self.queue go];
    }
}

- (void) _setupQueue
{
    [self.queue setShouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure:NO];
    [self.queue setRequestDidStartSelector:@selector(downloadDidStart:)];
    [self.queue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(downloadDidComplete:)];
    [self.queue setRequestDidFailSelector:@selector(downloadDidFailed:)];
    [self.queue setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueDidFinished:)];
    [self.queue setDownloadProgressDelegate:self.downloadProgress];
    [self.queue setDelegate:self];
    self.queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3;
//    self.queue.showAccurateProgress = YES;
}
```

First, pause function cancel all running operations, and recreate new requests push them into queue.
Then resume function unsuspends the queue.
Be noticed, request should not set setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES, otherwise the totalBytesToDownload will calculate wrong..If allowResumeForFileDownloads=NO, its value will be same as the count of requests in queue.

Here is my request fail handler, I add retry when file download fail. But I don't whant when I cancel a request, the retry mechanism will be invoked, so I set userInfo(ignore:true) to request object to prevent it happens.

```
- (void) downloadDidFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)req
{
    NSLog(@"request failed");
    NSLog(@"%d", self.queue.requestsCount);

    if(![self.queue showAccurateProgress])
    {
        [self.queue setTotalBytesToDownload:[self.queue totalBytesToDownload]-1];
        NSLog(@"totalBytesToDownload=%lld", self.queue.totalBytesToDownload);
    }

    NSDictionary * userInfo = req.userInfo;
    if([[userInfo valueForKey:@"ignore"] boolValue]) return; // ignore retry

    int retryTimes = [[req.userInfo objectForKey:@"retryTimes"] intValue];
    if(retryTimes<kMU_MaxRetry)
    {
        ++ retryTimes;
        NSLog(@"retry %d", retryTimes);
        ASIHTTPRequest * newReq = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:req.url];
        [newReq setDownloadDestinationPath:req.downloadDestinationPath];
        [newReq setTemporaryFileDownloadPath:req.temporaryFileDownloadPath];
        newReq.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", retryTimes] forKey:@"retryTimes"];
        [self.queue addOperation:newReq];

        NSLog(@"%d", self.queue.requestsCount);
    }else{  // reach max retry, fail it
        [self.failures addObject:req];
    }
}
```

I am not sure if there is a better solution, hope it can help you.